# Why (anti-)symmetric tensors are important in reducing the tensor product of representations of su($N$) and so($N$)?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

In the study of representation theory of the (complexified) Lie algebras su($N$) and so($N$), one often constructs the tensor product of their defining representations, and then reduces it to smaller irreducible representations by taking traces or symmetrizing/anti-symmetrizing the indices of the tensors that "realize" the representation.

But how is the (anti-)symmetrization step *motivated*? Why are (anti-)symmetric tensors important and related to irreducible representations of su($N$) and so($N$)? Can one please give a relatively intuitive and heuristic explanation?

---

**Edit**: Comments state that the symmetrization is motivated by the fact that the symmetric (permutation) group acts naturally on the tensor product space, and this action permutes with the Lie group action. Then the eigenspaces of a certain permutation naturally decompose the tensor representation as the direct sum of smaller ones. But to my knowledge we are only interested in eigenspaces of the permutations with eigenvalue $+ 1$ (*symmetric* tensors) and $-1$ (*anti-symmetric* tensors). Why eigenspaces with complex eigenvalues $e^{2\pi i/n}$ are not considered?

Comment: You are looking at an example of the [Schur functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor).  They come from the natural $S_n$-action on $V^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: Firstly, tensor products of representations are representations in a natural way. Then, the resulting action on tensor powers $V^{\otimes n}$ commutes with the natural action of $S_n$ given by swapping the order. This makes things like the symmetric and antisymmetric tensor powers invariant subspaces.

Comment: You might look at the simple case of $V \otimes V$ for a representation $V$ of a group $G$. There is a linear switching map $\sigma(v \otimes w) = w \otimes v$ which commutes with the action of the group, and so the representation will decompose into two subrepresentations: the 1-eigenspace of $\sigma$ (the symmetric square) and the -1-eigenspace of $\sigma$ (the antisymmetric square). One might then wonder if we can construct the symmetric square or antisymmetric square directly, rather than as a sub of $V \otimes V$, and we get symmetrisation.

Comment: @Joppy I know this example, but it seems to be *too simple* to be generalized. It does not help me understand if the eigenvectors of permutation cycles of length $n \ge 3$ (which have *complex* eigenvalues $e^{2 \pi i / n}$) help in reducing the tensor representation.